# Update apps with home-brew (youtube-dl)

Tags: homebrew, youtube, auto-update

Mainly i want to update youtube-dl on my mac. I have used Linux so for that updating any app is very simple: apt-get update youtube-dl. But how to do it on Mac using home-brew. Is there any kind of general command or something which will work for all the apps?

Comment: The (crossplatfom) instructions to update youtube-dl can be found as the first Q&A in the [Youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#faq).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run `brew update` first, then you can use `brew upgrade` to update all packages, or `brew upgrade youtube-dl` to update only `youtube-dl`.

Comment: Same situation, same question as OP. I installed with "brew" but trying to run the upgrade just now threw this error: `Error: youtube-dl 2015.07.28 already installed`. The `-U` option mentioned in the other answer worked with `sudo`, though.

Comment: @Davïd: I forgot to mention you need to run `brew update` first. If that doesn't work, maybe no one updated the youtube-dl formula and you should use `-U` if you need to update.

Answer (score 3):

Not for brew, but from the [documentation](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/documentation.html#gettingstarted), you can run `youtube-dl -U` to update.